# Java Mockito when accept arguments but conditionally

Tags: java, junit, mockito, conditional-statements, expectations

I am writing a test case using Mockito, and have to write expectation for a method (signature shown below)

```
public Object process(Employee e);
```

In my test class, I have to simulate my expectations as follows:

```
when(someClass.process("any Employee with id between 1 and 100.").thenReturn(object1);
when(someClass.process("any Employee with id between 101 and 200.").thenReturn(object2);
```

How can I set expectations conditionally.

Comment: what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: I have to some set expectations for a particular set of Employees. That I can check using condition inside `when`. May be if `Matchers` can help here, but my trials didn't work

Comment: have you looked at the `.thenAnswer()`? That might be able to help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using Mockito Answer

```
final ArgumentCaptor<Employee> employeeCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Employee.class);

Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
    Employee employee = employeeCaptor.getValue();
    if(employee.getId() > 1 && employee.getId() < 100)
      return object1;
    else if(employee.getId() > 101 && employee.getId() < 200)
      return object2;
    else someOtherObject;
}).when(someClass).process(employeeCaptor.capture());
```

Answer (score 0):

You case use the static method `Mockito.eq` which provides you with an *argument matcher* to specify returned values based on your input:

```
when(someClass.process(Mockito.eq("any Employee with id between 1 and 100.")).thenReturn(object1);
when(someClass.process(Mockito.eq("any Employee with id between 101 and 200.")).thenReturn(object2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mockito.doAnswer((invocation) -> {
            Employee argument = (Employee) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            int id = argument.getId();
            if (id >= 1 && id <= 100) {
                return object1;
            } else if (id >= 101 && id <= 200) {
                return object2;
            }
            return null; 
        }).when(someClass).process(Matchers.any(Employee.class));
```